# Don't want show all items of a model object in django

Tags: python, django

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
         return super(TaskManager, self).get_query_set().filter(Owner='jim')

class Task(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200)
    Notes = models.TextField('Description',max_length=2000, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,null=True, blank=True)
    Owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=owner_set)

    objects =  TaskManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Name
```

I have two models in my models.py, every Task has a project. But when i enter the Task page, it will list all the task by default. So i want it to list only the current user's Task `by default`. It is that the Task.Owner=current user.
Who can help me with this, thanks!

I have searched from the net and then get the solution:
I update the code i pasted just now above.
Thanks for all.

Comment: Can you post your urls.py file?

Comment: Is "Task Page" a view defined by you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do this!

```
Task.objects.filter(owner = current_user)
```

Update:

1) If you want to filter in you own custom template add this to your view code

2) If you are trying to customize the admin site do this,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import MyModel

class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 

    def queryset(self, request): 
        return super(TaskAdmin, self).queryset(request).filter(owner = request.user)

admin.site.register(Task, TaskAdmin)
```

Comment: If you have a custom view you have to place it there

Comment: If i don't have a custom view, i can not set a filter?

Comment: Enter the code in the view from where you are rendering the Task page, and send the filtered tasks as the context to the template.

Comment: Thanks Raunak, this is just what i want

Answer (score 1):

In the ModelAdmin class you should add:

```
class TaskAdmin(...):

    def queryset(self, request):
         qs = super(TaskAdmin, self).queryset(request)
         return qs.filter(Owner=request.user)
```

This will override the default queryset

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset

Comment: the click to filter, can be configure in the html template. you should use the admin if this is your only issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to modify the default filter of a model, make the model list not all items without the modelAdmin, because the modelAdmin just provide a filter which need manual click, i want to filter the model by default automaticlly

Comment: If you have additional information, it should be added as an edit or a comment to the original post, not as an answer!

Comment: Sorry for that,  i am not familiar with the rules of this forum