# Django old issue: Get current user in model

Tags: python, django, model

First i am sorry for asking this question, i am a new user for django. And i set up my project only by the models.Model

```
   ##models.py
    class Task(models.Model):
        Name = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200)
        Notes = models.TextField('Description',max_length=2000, null=True)
        Creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='TaskCreator', null=True, blank=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.Name

   ##admin.py
   class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
          list_display = ['Name', 'Owner','EstEndTime','LastModifiedTime','Statu']

   admin.site.register(Task,TaskAdmin)
```

I use the django's default admin for my site, i don't use any template of myself. now when a user log in and is going to create a task, i want to set the creator default by the current user. But i don't know how to get the current user in the models.Model.
I have looked up some information from the network, such as http://chewpichai.blogspot.tw/2007/09/using-user-info-outside-request-in.html, but it can not work. So who can tell me the method of getting current user in models.py file without the request. 
It preplexs me for a long time, i really wish someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: my answer isn't correct, i made a mistake reading your question. sorry.

Comment: If I may, I would add that class attributes should always start with a lowercase character. Capitals are for class names, by convention.

Answer (score 7):

You need to override the `save_model` in the Admin Class.

```
   class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
          list_display = ['Name', 'Owner','EstEndTime','LastModifiedTime','Statu']


          def save_model(self, request, task, form, change):
              task.Creator = request.user
              task.save()
```

read about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you answer more  detail since i am new.

Comment: def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
in thie function, how can i set the Task.Creator?

Comment: Now i have another question, that i want the Task model to show by filter by fefault, not by click the filter option which is set in modelAdmin like this:class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['Name','Owner','EstEndTime','LastModifiedTime','Statu']
    search_fields = ['Name']
    list_filter=('Statu','Project',DecadeByOwer,)

Comment: @jimwan I didn't understand, but if it is another question, start a new question, instead of us talking in comments :)

Comment: @YadenST, ok,this is the link for that question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599359/dont-want-show-all-items-of-a-model-object-in-django  . in that question, i have success to filter by the model.Manager, but i can only filte by a certain user rather that the current user. can you tell me how to improve that to make the Task object items not show all tasks but the current user's tasks.